# Поиск в массиве и плюс к значению

Tags: php

Имеется код:

```
  public function add($product, $count)
    {
        $array = json_decode('
            [{
                "product": "test-search",
                "count": "2"
            }, {
                "product": "example-3",
                "count": "2"
            }, {
                "product": "example-2",
                "count": "3"
            }, {
                "product": "example-1",
                "count": "4"
            }]
        ');
        $product = [
            'product' => $product,
            'count' => $count
        ];
        array_unshift($array, $product);
    }
```

Как осуществить поиск по этому массиву и найти элемент test-search и если элемент нашелся прибавить значение из $count?

Answer (score 1):

```
function add(&$array, $product, $count){
    foreach($array as &$el){
        if($el['product'] === $product){
            $el['count'] += $count;
            return;
        }
    }
    array_unshift($array, ['product' => $product, 'count' => $count]);
}

$array = json_decode('
        [{
            "product": "test-search",
            "count": "2"
        }, {
            "product": "example-3",
            "count": "2"
        }, {
            "product": "example-2",
            "count": "3"
        }, {
            "product": "example-1",
            "count": "4"
        }]
    ', true);
add($array, "test-search", 5);
add($array, "test-search2", 5);
var_dump($array);
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/34068198257ce44bac390794763d1f8c81581c95)

Comment: А как использовать весь этот код в пределах одной функции? Без выноса за пределы функции?

Comment: А почему такое странное условие? Вы в курсе, что функция из вашего вопроса вообще никакой полезной нагрузки не несет - полученный массив уничтожается сразу по завершению работы функции

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array = json_decode('
    [{
        "product": "test-search",
        "count": "2"
    }, {
        "product": "example-3",
        "count": "2"
    }, {
        "product": "example-2",
        "count": "3"
    }, {
        "product": "example-1",
        "count": "4"
    }]
');

foreach($array as $a) {
    $product[] = $a->product;
}
$search = array_search('test-search', $product);
$array[$search]->count++;

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: 1. Не `++`, а `+=$count` 2. А если не нашелся?

Comment: @rjhdby исправь или удали если не трудно, уже с телефона)